# unable to load an external table from a file in Hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

I am not able to load an external table in Hue.
It works through the hive command shell.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/hive_input/student_cse_1.txt' 
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE student_partition PARTITION(course = 'cse', year = 1);
```

It gave this error in cloudera manager:

```
Your query has the following error(s):
> OK FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''/home/cloudera/hive_input/student_cse_1.txt'': 
No files matching path file:/home/cloudera/hive_input/student_cse_1.txt
```

Any configuration issue?

Comment: hive or beeline CLI? how are you connecting to Hive? through JDBC?

Comment: I am connecting to hive through Hue.

Comment: it is currently expecting the file to be on HiveServer when using `LOCAL` option. Move the file to HDFS and use `LOAD DATA INPATH ... ` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, how do we load using "load data local inpath ... "  in Hue Hive editor ?

Comment: as mentioned earlier, if you have access to hive server file system, place the file there and use the LOCAL INPATH option.

Comment: How do I check if I have the access to hive server ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am connecting to hive through Hue

Beeline and Hive CLI do have access to your **local** `/home` directory, Hue does not.

[Hue has a table creation UI](http://gethue.com/import-data-to-be-queried-via-the-self-service-drag-drop-create-table-wizard/), but the (previous) way to use Hue to create Hive tables is to

1. Upload data to HDFS
2. Create table schema on top of an `EXTERNAL TABLE... LOCATION '/path/to/directory_with_file'`

Comment: I uploaded file to hdfs. Then I ran this command.  load data inpath 'student1.txt' into table student1.  It gave error : OK FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''student1.txt'': No files matching path hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hue/student1.txt

Comment: Please give the full HDFS path to the query , or look at the error and put the file there